# Lost car in Gta Online

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

I bought my second house in Gta Online on my ps4. I wanted to drive from first to second garage. I drove out of garage in my zentorno and bought elegy at zentorno's place. When I swapped elegy with zentorno, my expensive car has been lost on the map. I can't get it from mechanic or something like this. Please help!

Comment: is it destroyed? Phoned insurance?

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're describing is where you replace one expensive car with another in your first garage. This means that your previous car's tracker would have been removed and it wouldn't have been available from your garage... If this is what you're experiencing you mightn't be able to get your car back.

The only way I know to solve this is to re-buy your car and store it in your other garage and to make sure that it is going to your other garage before you store it. Otherwise I cannot help. But that is my opinion.